# Direction of normal vector if the flux is outward a circle

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

I have the vector field $\vec{F}(x,y)=(x,y)$, the circle of radius 1 and the flux going outward.

Thus, $\vec{N} = \pm(-cos t, -sint)$, but how do I know if the normal vector is positive of negative?

Comment: What does "outward" mean?

Comment: Just plug in $t=0$. Which choice makes sense?

Comment: I'm not convinced.
@TedShifrin outward the circle

Comment: So is it the position vector or its negative that points outward?

Comment: @TedShifrin
The flux of $F$ points outward.

Comment: Flux doesn’t point anywhere. It is a number. You want the dot product of $F$ with the outward-pointing *normal vector*. The normal in this case is either the position vector or its negative. Answer my question.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can I post a link from upenn. They talk about outward flux.

Comment: This is shorthand for precisely what I explained.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You said "You want the dot product of F with the outward-pointing normal vector. The normal in this case is either the position vector or its negative" This is exactly my question. How to know if the normal vector is negative or positive.